# I'm having problems adding a new search criteria to Solr

Tags: solr, solr4

Facts

1. Solr is installed and has indexed the user core.
2. I've added the field "ssotoken" to the schema.xml.
3. I've re-indexed the Solr core after adding the "ssotoken" field to the user core.

I can see the query contain "ssotoken" but the search criteria is not returning anything.

Please note that other field criterias return a result-set in xml format.

Please let me know what other details you need.

I have struggled with this for a couple of days now. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you search for a document containing a ssotoken, does it have a value in the ssotoken field? (id:foo, where foo is the id of a document that has the ssotoken). Is the field set to indexed?

Comment: The filed is set to indexed, however ssotoken appears in xml format in the resultset as <str name="ssotoken"/> with no value, even though in SQL server "ssotoken" is "associatedUserToken" how do I tell Solr that the field added to schema.xml ("ssotoken") is an index for "associatedUserToken" in SQL Server?

Comment: That depends on how you're importing data to Solr. If you're using DIH, you can probably add a AS ssotoken field alias in the SQL query you use to fetch data. Since the fields are empty in your index now, you won't be able to find them if you're using it as a search criteria.

Comment: I've decided to take a step back and understand the fundamentals of Solr. I have experience with Apache so that part won't be that hard.

Comment: We have a search page that's already searching Solr. I want to add an additional search criteria and NOT display it. Would I have to add an index to schema.xml? Or would I have to modify the DIH  as well?